# Get rid of override reason for TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc, team-explorer

I'd like to get rid of an override reason for some code that I've been working on, where previous shelvesets I made from it required an override reason to deal with checkin policy warnings, but where the current version does not.

However, while I can see in Team Explorer the field for override reason when my code violates checkin policy, I can't see the field when it doesn't violate the policy.

Short of deliberately making my code violate checkin policy, how can I empty out the override reason?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by you problem, the override reason only appears if you are not satisfying a condition.  If you do satisfy all condition it will not show up.  So what are you trying to do? It seems you want to override reason box to show while satisfying all the policy.  Just put the "reason" in the comment and all policy will be satisfied and you'll have your reason for checkin no?

Comment: @Etienne I previously had an override reason, and now I want to get rid of it.

Comment: Hi  Andrew Grimm, we were trying to reproduce your issue, but couldn't. Kindly check my updated reply and comment if this helps. Not sure if totally get your point. Besides, you could also add a screenshot and detail step to reproduce  the issue, which would be helpful.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT I'll try to do so when I have time at work.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm you could disable the required policy that would remove the need for an override but then you would be forced to input comments.  That is usually a corporate or at least team standard though.  You can't remove the policy override box unless you remove the policy altogether.

Answer (score -1):

The shelveset saves and stores not only your file revisions, but also the Comment, the list of Related Work Items, **and check-in notes (if you evaluate policies before shelving)**.

[image]

Select either of the following check boxes:

- *Preserve pending change locally* : By default, this check box is selected. When this check box is selected, your pending changes
  (including the comment and the Related Work Items list) are not
  removed from your workspace. If you want to clean your workspace to
  work on another task, you should clear this check box.
- *Evaluate Policies and check-in notes before shelving*: When you select this check box, all check-in policies are evaluated before the
  shelveset is created.

So you could uncheck **Evaluate Policies and check-in notes before shelving** when you are trying to unshelve. This will not keep any override reason in Team Explore.

If there is any override reason cached in Team Explore. Just manually delete them.

According to your situation, since you are working on multiple shelvesets and not check in pending changes frequently.

Since check in policy will only validate when you are trying to check in pending changes. There is no need to Evaluate Policies and check-in notes for all shelvesets each time. Which may make things complicated and confused.

The best way is unchecking this option during the shelve. And make sure you do not 
violate  the policy after finally check in option.

Hope this is clearly and helpful.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I've changed my pending changes to satisfy the policies, so it no longer needs an override reason, but the override reason added previously still gets added to new shelves when I shelf my changes.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm  Sorry for any misunderstanding.  `However, while I can see in Team Explorer the field for override reason when my code violates check in policy, I can't see the field when it doesn't violate the policy.` My original reply was trying to answer this part. It's an expected behavior. And  one more point, even though you have not violate the policy finally when you are trying to check in pending changes, if you used to violate the policy during/before  checking the pending changes, you will still see the override reason. However, you could ignore it and leave it empty , then check in.

Comment: Hi Andrew Grimm, Besides I have also update my reply according to your latest comment.  `I've changed my pending changes to satisfy the policies, so it no longer needs an override reason, but the override reason added previously still gets added to new shelves when I shelf my changes.` Cause you have ever not satisfied the check in policy before, so there will always have a Policy Warning field  until this pending changes checked in and you are trying to check next. You could also choose to uncheck Evaluate Policies and check-in notes before shelving, this will not save any override reason.